# How to make rope animations without physics

Tags: modeling, animation, physics

[image]

Hey guys, I have a animation from mixamo and want to combine it rope which I created but I have no clue how to do it. I made all rope animations tutorialbased physic but I think collision problem appears with hands always tried with many different settings and its really hard to simulate. Thanks for your help guys

Comment: maybe use a curve modifier for your rope and hook some of the curve vertices so that you can animate it?

Comment: Is it for a game or video?  I don't use the physics engine for rope emulation, rather the method @Moonboots suggested and without too much difficulty once you get the hang of it. Can elaborate if you're interested.